# Storybook docs page displays extra JSDOC tags in description

Tags: reactjs, jsdoc, storybook

My component's description on the Storybook Docs page is picking up extra tags stuff from the JSDocs in addition to the description.

How can I go about displaying only the "description part" of the JSDOC description?

I've attempted explicitly specifying a `@description` tag but that didn't do anything.

[image]

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution?

Comment: any update on this? 2 years and no support? not to throw shade, but it seems like storybook doesn't understand jsdocs is used